# Problemas leer mensaje iot hub Azure con c#

Tags: c#, azure

He creado un Centro de Iot de Azure y he configurado un evento para que almacene los mensajes de telemetría en un cola de un storage. Mi idea es consumirlos despues de esta cola. Pero el problemas es que cuando accedo al mensaje, el body en lugar de ser el json que yo escribo con el cliente es una cadena que parece encriptada. ¿como puedo decodificarla? El codigo del dispositivo esta hecho con el ejemplo de azure y mando los datos como un json.

El mensaje que estoy enviando desde el dispositivo es este `{"temperature":20.0,"humidity":60.0}` 
y para enviarlo en el ejemplo hace esto `var messageAscii = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageString);`

Y cuando recupero el mensaje recibo este string: `eyJ0ZW1wZXJhdHVyZSI6MjAuMCwiaHVtaWRpdHkiOjYwLjB9`

Comment: Colocar tu codigo para que te ayuden.

Answer (score 0):

En el momento de enviar supongo que tienes algo similar a :

```
        var telemetryDataPoint = new
        {
            temperature = currentTemperature,
            humidity = currentHumidity
        };
        var messageString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(telemetryDataPoint);
        var message = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageString));
        // Send the telemetry message
        await _deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
```

Luego en el procesador necesitas algo similar a :

```
static async Task IoTMessagesProcessor(string partition, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var eventHubReceiver = s_eventHubClient.CreateReceiver("[ConsumerGroupName]", partition, EventPosition.FromEnqueuedTime(DateTime.Now));
    while (true)
    {
        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) break;
        Console.WriteLine("Listening messages on: " + partition);
        // Check for EventData
        var events = await eventHubReceiver.ReceiveAsync(100);
        // If there is data in the batch, process it.
        if (events == null) continue;
        foreach (EventData eventData in events)
        {
            string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.Body.Array);
            Console.WriteLine("  {0}:", data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, @PepLluis. Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español. Intenta añadir la explicación del código para que la comunidad pueda saber más o menos lo que hace. Recuerda que la respuesta no es solo para ayudar a quién pregunta sino para dejar una ayuda para el resto de personas que puedan tener la misma duda. Te dejo un enlace al apartado de como responder [https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer]. Saludos.

Comment: Ok, Cuando tenga un enlace de un ejemplo en git, lo referenciare. Gracias